# How to log the debug run by a pipeline in azure?

Tags: azure, logging, parameter-passing, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I know only those pipelines that are triggered will show up in the monitor, but i would like to get logs of the debug runs as well, like how many rows have been written/inserted and other details for an azure data factory pipeline?

Is this feasible in azure?
Also is there a log where we can see what all changes were made to the datawarehouse(creation,modification) and at what time, this will be really helpful?

Thanks !!! thanks!!!! Thank you sooo much!:)

Comment: Hi Monsta, you've asked several questions here. You are likely to get better responses if you ask them as separate questions. In the meantime, based on your questions, I believe you are using the Copy activity? You may want to investigate Data Flows to solve these issues. Derived Column with expressions can easily solve #2 and #3. I don't believe #1 is possible.

Comment: Agree with Joel, use Data Flows in ADF for these requirements.

#1 would be achieved also by Data Flows. Add a Data Flow activity in your pipeline to read the JSON output from the previous activity and write it to a log file.

I have a video tutorial for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UC__LOyuf8M

Comment: I am using Dataflow.

Comment: hi,Monsta.Any further help you need? I think above comments already solve your issue.(Specially the video)Would you please summarize them as an answer for others' reference? Thank you in advance.